# Need help with capacitor

Tags: capacitor, electrical

Hello I have a circuit here that turns on an led when the switch at the bottom opens up. My first problem is that I would like a NO push button that turns off the LED when it’s hit. But I would also like the light to stay on for let’s say 5 seconds after that push button is hit. That’s why I tried adding the capacitor at the top, I’m obviously way off on basic capacitance and need to do more research,  but any help you could give me would be appreciated[image]

Comment: Is it ok if during those 5 seconds, the LED is getting dimmer and dimmer?  If not, how complicated are you willing to go with this project?

Comment: yup that's not a problem at all

Comment: What your circuit will do: switch open: LED = on, switch closed: LED is off. On/off switching of LED is **immediate**. When switching **on** the capacitor will discharge through the LED making the LED light up very brightly (possibly damaging it). Switching off will be immediate. I suggest researching and trying to understand existing circuits. As a a beginner, "designing" your own circuit will usually only get you frustrated and confused. First learn from others, then when you have mastered those circuits are you ready to design your own.

Comment: *a NO push button that turns off the LED when it’s hit* ... *the light to stay on for 5 seconds after that push button is hit* I see a contradiction, so the NO button is pressed, does the LED then need to turn off of turn on and stay on for 5 seconds? If you make clear what you want I'm sure I can draw you a circuit that can do the job. Reply in a comment using @Bimpelrekkie so that I get a notification.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie that’s really good advice actually! Appreciate that. I think Im going to scrap the idea and just do one I saw online that worked